# Printing one iteration from for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working with for loop right now and under an assumption that candies can somehow multiply themselves overtime, where it always starts with one candy and multiply in a function of y = ax + b in 1 second and resulting y value carry over to time = 2 seconds. for example:

```
a = 3 #this is a in ax+b
b = 1 #this is b in ax+b
t = 3 #this is time in seconds

x = 1
for t in range(t):
    t+=1
    x=(a*x)+b
    print('str(x) + ' candies after '+str(t)+' seconds')
```

this code gives me three outputs, which are

```
4 candies after 1 seconds
13 candies after 2 seconds
40 candies after 3 seconds
```

The numbers are right, but the issue is that I just want to print the last statement. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As for printing, do so **after** the `for` loop. Just unindent the `print` line.

Comment: my bad that should have been t

Comment: You shouldn't really reuse the name `t` for both the total time and the loop iteration value. Also, python doesn't limit you to 1-character variables, your code would be clearer if you used `candies` instead of `x` and `second` instead of `t`, `time` instead of `t` for the total time in seconds, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by moving the print statement out of for loop

```
for t in range(t):
    t+=1
    x=(a*x)+b
print(str(x) + ' candies after '+str(t)+' seconds')
# 40 candies after 3 seconds
```

You may also change one the variables t to some other variable. 
eg.

```
a = 3 #this is a in ax+b
b = 1 #this is b in ax+b
t = 3 #this is time in seconds

x = 1
for i in range(t):
    i+=1
    x=(a*x)+b
print(str(x) + ' candies after '+str(i)+' seconds')
```

Comment: If you are going to change `t` to `i` in the loop, you need to replace **all the other `t` occurrences after the `for` line too**.